# displaying list of holidays for each month

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this code to display calendar in web page:

```
<script>
                $('#calendar').datepicker({
                inline: true,
                firstDay: 1,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun','Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
            });
 </script>
```

Now I want to display holiday list for each month. So I used this code:

```
<script>

    var unavailableDates = ["16-10-2013", "4-11-2013", "25-12-2013"];

   function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Holiday"];
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#calendar-dep").datepicker({numberOfMonths: 2, showCurrentAtPos: 0,minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

      $("#calendar-return").datepicker({numberOfMonths: 2, showCurrentAtPos: 0,minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

})


   </script>
```

But holiday list isn't getting displayed. How can I write a more appropriate code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    dmy = date.getDay() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear(); //Use GetDay() instead of Getdate()
```

or You can Use this

```
    function unavailable(date) {
      var day= date.substring(0, 2);
        var month = date.substring(3, 5);
        var year = date.substring(6, 10);

        var myDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
if ($.inArray(myDate , unavailableDates) == -1) {
    return [true, ""];
} else {
    return [false, "", "Holiday"];
}
}
```

Comment: I bet you never tested this. It simply won’t work. `date = 10-2-2014`.

Answer (score 0):

`date.getDate()` returns Javascript’s [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instance. Whether you want to use this sort of comparision:

```
var d = date.getDate(); // plain javascript Date object
dmy = d.getDay() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +  d.getFullYear();
```

Please also note that month here might have either 1 or 2 digits. Hope this helps.